# Unable to update multiple div with same id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop a countdown timer which displays sales on my webpage on different locations (all the `div`s are being managed using PHP). All the countdown timers have same `id` and exists within same page.

When i try to update content of all countdown using `id`, it works only for first `div`.

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <p id="countdown"></p>

    <script>
        var end = new Date('03/24/2016 08:00 PM');

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }

            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' Days ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + ' Hours ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' Mins ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + ' Secs';
        }
        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: id="countdown" - you can use it only once, id must be unique

Comment: Why don't you assign classes it is for that purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id must be unique. You can use `class` instead. You can get all elements by class name using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). After that you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over all elements and set `innerHTML` property.

```
<p class="countdown"></p>
<p class="countdown"></p>
<p class="countdown"></p>
<p class="countdown"></p>
<p class="countdown"></p>
<p class="countdown"></p>

<script>
    var end = new Date('03/24/2016 08:00 PM');  

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function setAllCountdownInnerHtml(html) {
        var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName('countdown');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(allElements, function(ele) {
            ele.innerHTML = html;
        });
    }

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            setAllCountdownInnerHtml('EXPIRED!');
            return;
        }

        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        var html = days + ' Days ' + hours + ' Hours ' + minutes + ' Mins ' + seconds + ' Secs';
        setAllCountdownInnerHtml(html);
     }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
```

See demo here https://jsfiddle.net/v3y4b3ux/

Answer (score 0):

Rename your ids to be unique...

```
<p id="countdown1"></p>
<p id="countdown2"></p>
<p id="countdown3"></p>
<p id="countdown4"></p>
<p id="countdown5"></p>
```

then use a for loop to write to each one separately...

```
var time = days + ' Days ' + hours + ' Hours ' + minutes + ' Mins ' + seconds + ' Secs';
for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  document.getElementById('countdown' + i).innerHTML = time;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, though i wanted to use it in php script and this tag will be in a div which is being looped through php.

I'll not be able to assign different ids as i want my code to work on loop as sale item. 

See = 

www.wayshopping.com for clarification